# 2sxc Intellisense in VSCode

Tags: 2sxc

As stated [in the 2sxc style guide](https://docs.2sxc.org/basics/style-guide/style-guide-2020.html#use-visual-studio-code), VS Code is the recommended editor for development. However, we are unable to get Intellisense working for the C# portions of code (including Razor and custom C# Web APIs). It appears to me that the official C# Language extension for VS Code expects a project `.sln` file for any language features to work, which 2sxc apps do not have/use. Is there a structure to a solution file we could use to have C# Intellisense work? Or, should we be opening our apps from a different folder, or in a different editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck - we found this challenging as well, and just recently got it to work ;)

Check out the instructions here https://go.2sxc.org/vscode

Comment: Oooooh, this is very exciting! Will report back after trying it out

Comment: It seems like https://r.2sxc.org/ is blocked on my work network (maybe got flagged for being a redirect URL or something? not sure. For anyone else coming to this question, the link goes to https://docs.2sxc.org/guides/vscode/index.html currently.

Comment: This worked! Getting errors now for things like `System.Web.Http`, `DotNetNuke.Web.Api`, and `DotNetNuke.Security` but I can easily find those DLLs and include them (should be standard relative directory to 2sxc apps)

Comment: I got it working too. This is fantastic!